# Postgres set final value based on some condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

My Postgres Table has a column called status which consists of complete, failed or running.
Based on these value I want to set the final result 
if all completed then final result = completed
if one failed then result = failed
if one running and no failed entry then the result is running.

```
code | status   | parent_code
1    | complete |      3
2    | running  |      3
3    | ----     |
```

In the above table, for code = 3 I want to set the status to running.

Also if someone can tell me how to set the trigger for the same, whenever changes happen I want to keep the value of parent updated.

Comment: To what does `parent_code` correspond?

Comment: Parent_code correspond to first column `code`

Comment: So your table will always have 2 records per process ?  how parent_code is decided ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a sub-query using filtered aggregation to count the total number and the number of failed, running and completed rows and use that for an UPDATE statement:

```
update the_table tt
   set status = case 
                   when x.failed > 0 then 'failed'
                   when x.running > 0 then 'running'
                   when x.total_rows = x.completed then 'completed'
                end
from (
  select parent_code, 
         count(*) as total_rows,
         count(*) filter (where status = 'running') as running,
         count(*) filter (where status = 'failed') as failed,
         count(*) filter (where status = 'completed') as completed
  from the_table
  where parent_code is not null
  group by parent_code
) x 
where tt.parent_code is null   
  and tt.code = x.parent_code
```

Answer (score 1):

A horse with no names answer is just fine (and I've upvoted it).  This is a suggestion on a simplification:

```
update the_table tt
    set status = p.status
    from (select parent_code, 
                 coalesce(max(status) filter (where status = 'failed'),
                          max(status) filter (where status = 'running'),
                          max(status) filter (where status = 'completed')
                         )
           from the_table
           group by parent_code
          ) p 
    where tt.parent_code is null and 
          tt.code = p.parent_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the above answer given by @a_horse_with_no_name and @Gordon Linoff is correct.
Here I have converted it to stored procedure and written a trigger for the same.
It might be helpful for someone.

1. Writing a Stored Procedure.
2. Creating a trigger.

#### Writing a Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UpdateStatus()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
update the_table tt
   set status = case 
                   when x.failed > 0 then 'failed'
                   when x.running > 0 then 'running'
                   when x.total_rows = x.completed then 'completed'
                end
from (
  select parent_code, 
         count(*) as total_rows,
         count(*) filter (where device_discovery_status = 'running') as running,
         count(*) filter (where device_discovery_status = 'failed') as failed,
         count(*) filter (where device_discovery_status = 'completed') as completed
  from the_table
  where parent_code is not null
  group by parent_code
) x 
where tt.parent_code is null   
  and tt.code = x.parent_code;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Creating a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_status_on_change
    AFTER UPDATE ON the_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE UpdateStatus();
```

So whenever a status gets changed `update_status_on_change` trigger will be triggered and it will set the final status accordingly.

Comment: I would make that a statement level trigger, so it's only fired once even if you insert or update thousands of rows

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @a_horse_with_no_name.
I will explore the statement-level trigger.